# encrypt multiple systems (Windows 7 + deb)

Tags: windows-7, debian, encryption, grub, truecrypt

I've installed two operating system on single drive with 3 partitions (#1 Windows 7, #2 Debian Squeeze, #some data). Grub 2 is installed in MBR and lets me choose which system to boot.
I would encrypt the 1st system partition containing Windows 7. I tried to do this using TrueCrypt under Windows, but it says that encrypting Windows system with other loader (not Windows loader, Grub in my case) is not supported. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will take some work, but it is quite possible.

http://www.steve-oh.com/blog/index.php/ubuntu-vista-dual-boot-full-encryption-with-truecrypt/

Meh, this link is for Ubuntu, but I think it is close enough.  Let us know how it works out!

Comment: Those instructions aren't for GRUB 2.

Answer (score 4):

I've done it :) but not exactly like in your link, because of some kind of problem (bug?) in Grub2 (tutorial is with grub "1" but I've Grub2), specifically in this:

> title Windows Vista/Longhorn
>   rootnoverify (hd0,0) makeactive
>   **chainloader (hd0,1)/truecrypt.mbr**
>   boot

The problem is known and posted on many forums.

My solution was:

1. Encrypt Windows7 system partition using truecrypt, selecting Single boot and overwriting Grub2 loader with truecrypt loader
2. Boot Debian from Rescue CD and install grub2 bootloader NOT on MBR but on /dev/sda3 which is Debian / partition (so truecrypt loader was not overrided)

Now while booting truecrypt bootmenu is shown and if I'd access Win7 I'm entering password, but if I'd enter debian (via Grub2) I hit esc key and then truecrypt loader is searching all other partitions for boot loader and finding Grub2 which resides on /dev/sda3 and load system properly.

I think its the best way to do this for now (until sb find resolution for Grub2 to read /boot/truecrypt.mbr without errors).

Comment: I'm glad that worked out.  I'm not a dual booter myself.  Prefer VMs.